# The probability of choosing a 5 element subset from the set {1,2,...,20}, with 1 element from{1,4,6,8,9} and 1 from{11,13,17,19} but 0 from {2,3,5,7}

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I need to make a 5 element subset using at least one of {11, 13, 17, 19} and at least one of {1, 4, 6, 8, 9} from the set of the first twenty integers but I cannot use any of {2, 3, 5, 7}. I tried doing
 $$ \frac {\left({16 \choose 5}  - {11 \choose 5}\right) \left({16 \choose 5} - {12 \choose 5}\right)}{{20 \choose 5}} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: For starters, it might be helpful to mention the *other* set: {10,12,14,16,18,20}. You will be choosing between 0 and 3 elements from this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not correct.  You should have some words explaining how you got your answer.  $16 \choose 5$ is the number of ways to select five elements without $2,3,5,7$.  It is a good start.  You then subtract $11 \choose 5$ which is the number of ways to select five elements without $2,3,5,7$ nor $1,4,6,8,9$.  Instead of multiplying, you should then subtract $12 \choose 5$, but now you have double subtracted the cases missing one of $1,4,6,8,9$ and one of $11,13,17,19$, so you have to add them back in.  See the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).